# Laminas - get partial helper in controller

Tags: php, laminas

Is there a way to access a partial view helper in controller?

In old spring application I use this code

```
private function  currentViewHelperManager(){
    $viewHelperManager =  $this->getEvent()->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('viewHelperManager');
    return $viewHelperManager;
}
```

but in laminas doesn't works.

Comment: This works (use a capital "V" instead of lowercase): `$this->getEvent()->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('ViewHelperManager')`

Comment: It works. Please make comment as answer.